# BigQuery cannot find GeoPandas

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, geopandas, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to load a BigQuery table into a GeoDataFrame via:

```
gdf = \
client.query("SELECT * FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`")\
      .result()\
      .to_geodataframe()
```

However, I get **`ValueError: The geopandas library is not installed`**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_782/24642811.py in <module>
      1 gdf = \
----> 2 client.query("SELECT * FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`")\
      3       .result()\
      4       .to_geodataframe()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py in to_geodataframe(self, bqstorage_client, dtypes, progress_bar_type, create_bqstorage_client, date_as_object, geography_column)
   2098         """
   2099         if geopandas is None:
-> 2100             raise ValueError(_NO_GEOPANDAS_ERROR)
   2101 
   2102         geography_columns = set(

ValueError: The geopandas library is not installed, please install geopandas to use the to_geodataframe() function.
```

But `geopandas` is definitely installed. `import geopandas` works, `!pip3 install geopandas` results in `Requirement already satisfied` messages. I am on a Vertex AI workbench Jupyter notebook.

Loading the data to a Pandas dataframe works fine:

```
df = \
client.query("SELECT * FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`")\
      .result()\
      .to_dataframe()
```

I read about `to_geodataframe()` [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator#google_cloud_bigquery_table_RowIterator_to_geodataframe).

**How could I fix the `to_geodataframe()` attribute of the `RowIterator` object `` client.query("SELECT * FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`").result() ``?**

Comment: is it possible bigquery is installed in your root conda env but geopandas is in an environment? also I would strongly recommend against installing geopandas with pip. try deleting your env and reinstalling all packages, including geopandas and google-bigquery, with conda.

Comment: You can try to reinstall, but in a different way, installing from source, in this case from github the last version, using this command.“pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git”. You can see this [documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#installing-from-source) with the steps.